# How can Python's socket (UDP) be used to connect different machines on different WiFi?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I've been trying to set up a game to play with my friends. We all live in different places and have different IP, WiFi etc. I started coding on my own computer using `socket` using `SOCK_DGRAM`. It worked fine when I ran the server and client code on my own computer, but when my friends tried to run the client code they couldn't send anything to my server. No error was thrown, what they sent just wasn't picked up by my server.

Here is the server code:

```
    import socket

    host = "192.168.88.191"
    port = 2000
    connections = Connections() # Where I store my friends' way of contacting the server
    player_list = [] # A list of players to be used by my Players class

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.setblocking(False)

    print("Server started")
    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            got_data = True
        except OSError:
            got_data = False

        if got_data:
            if not addr in connections.addresses:
                connections.addresses.append(addr) # Store all new addresses
                player_list.append(Players(len(player_list))) # Append to player list (don't worry about this part)

            data = data.decode("utf-8")

            print("Message from " + str(addr) + ": " + data)
            player_list[int(addr[1] - 2001)].move(data, player_list) # Function for game logic

            message = ""
            for player in player_list:
                message += str(player.number) + " " + str(player.x) + " " + str(player.y) + "," # Make the message that I want to send
            message = message[:-1]
            print("Sending: " + message)
            for address in connections.addresses:
                s.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), address)
```

Here is the client code:

```
class Sock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "192.168.88.191"
        self.port = 2000

        self.server = (self.host, 2000)
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        while True:
            try:
                print("Trying to connect on port " + str(self.port))
                self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
            except OSError:
                self.port += 1
            else:
                self.s.setblocking(False)
                print("Connected on port " + str(self.port) + "!")
                break

    def send_data(self, message):
        print("Sending: " + message)
        self.s.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), self.server)

    def recieve_data(self):
        try:
            data, addr = self.s.recvfrom(1024)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            print("Recieved from server: " + data)
            return data
        except socket.error:
            pass
```

My IP is 192.168.88.191. I would assume that my friends need to use their IP in the client code, but where? I know that you can find your IP by doing `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`

EDIT: This client code didn't actually work, it tried every port until it reached the highest port possible and threw an error. We did some adjustments to the code and got it to connect, but the server still didn't recieve anything. The client could send just fine, but the server didn't recieve. I'm not 100% about the adjustment in question, but I think we replaced: `self.server = (self.host, 2000)` with: `self.server = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 2000)` although as I said I don't know if that's exacly what we did.

Comment: I have posted a similar question, but with simpler code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547006/python-socket-communication-across-networks-not-working