# Python Socket communication across networks not working

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to set up communication between me and my friend's computer using the *socket* module. I run the server code on my computer and he runs the client code on his computer. Here is the code:

Server:

```
import socket

host = "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX" # IP of my computer
port = 2000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))

addrs = []

print("Server started")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    if not addr in addrs:
        addrs.append(addr)
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    print("Recieved: " + str(data))
    print("Sending: " + data)
    for add in addrs:
        s.sendto(data.encode("utf-8"), add)
```

Client:

```
import socket
import time

host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" # External IP of my router
port = 2001

server = (host, port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setblocking(False)

while True:
    message = "Test message"
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Sending: " + message)
    s.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), server)
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    except BlockingIOError:
        pass
    else:
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        print("Recieved: " + str(data))
```

Note: The port in the client vs. server code is different to make sure that my port forwarding is actually doing something.

I have set up port forwarding on my router. Everything works fine when I run both scripts on my computer (or even another computer connected to the same WiFi as mine) and I know that the port forwarding is doing its thing. However, when my friend (**who is connected to a different WiFi**) runs the client code, it doesn't work. No error is thrown, but he sends data which neither my computer nor the router's port forwarding rule recieves.

Could this problem originate from my code, or is it more likely to be because of my router not being properly set up?

Comment: Maybe try to use a TCP socket by using `socket.SOCK_STREAM` instead of `socket.SOCK_DGRAM`

Comment: Or test it without the one-second timeout but check `data != b''` before printing it and comment out the `print('Sending ...')` so you don't get a lot of empty messages that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is actually 100% correct, the error was in my port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I setup a HotSpot my Android Phone. which in this case is your "Router", used my phone's IP Address. and On the computer tried to run your client code, its sending test messages on the client:

Sending: Test message
Sending: Test message
Sending: Test message
Sending: Test message
....

but I'm receiving nothing on your Server, still saying server started.

so I configured your host variable on the "Client App" like so, also your ports are not consistent 2000 on server and 2001 on client:

host = "" # External IP of my router
port = 2000
NOTE!! I left the host Empty

Because I think for some reason the server is hosted locally on the pc, you are running the server on. This way i can also Connect locally from the same computer I ran the server app with:

host = "localhost" # External IP of my router

on the your client app.

this is how everything looks.

**Server Code**
run this on your comuter.

```
import socket

host = "" # IP of my computer
port = 2000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))

addrs = []

print("Server started")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    if not addr in addrs:
        addrs.append(addr)
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    print("Recieved: " + str(data))
    print("Sending: " + data)
    for add in addrs:
        s.sendto(data.encode("utf-8"), add)
```

Depending on where you ran your serverApp. use the IP of the computer running the server. I'm Still learning so I don't know how to set it up to use your router's IP.

**ClientApp Code**
run this on your friend computer or more. or on android even.

```
import socket
import time

host = "ip_of_the_computer_the_server_is_running_on" # connecting from another computer
#host = "localhost" # If you connecting locally

port = 2000

server = (host, port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setblocking(False)

while True:
    message = "Test message"
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Sending: " + message)
    s.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), server)
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    except BlockingIOError:
        pass
    else:
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        print("Recieved: " + str(data))
```

***And use Your router only for same AP Connection.***
Tested with my TOTO-LINK IT WORKS FINE. as long as I don't use my router's IP On the client host.

**Demonstrations**
*Server* 
[image: Server Code Running and recieving from Android and localhost]

*CLient*

[image: Client on computer Sending Tests]

*Client On Mobile*
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. I have edited my question to emphasise that my friend is on a different WiFi than me (that is my actual problem). Does your answer still apply then?

Comment: Okay, I see I don't think it applies. cos I don't understand how you want to network if they are on different WIFI networks. I haven't practiced remote  access.

Comment: I will try doing this too. its interesting. I think there is something moore to it to enable remote connection.